# jarsigner: unable to open jar file: app-release-unsigned.apk

Tags: android, cordova, apk, command-prompt, jarsigner

I am currently working on cordova project and I tried to generate key with the set of lines

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore <myappname.keystore> -alias <myappname> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I also generated a keystore after that I used the below line

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <myappname.keystore> app-release-unsigned.apk <myappname>
```

but I get this issue

> jarsigner: unable to open jar file: app-release-unsigned.apk

Can anyone help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help someone:
What worked for was placing the whole path from the src folder. Example:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-app-key.keystore platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk app_alias
```

I'm using Cordova. The app was developed in Ionic

Answer (score 2):

hey I know this kind of late to answer, but also came to this issue and i kept doing was copy paste the **jarsigner** code instead of giving the path to the APK below is the code

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -my-release-key.keystore <whatever_the_path_is_to_your_apk_file\app-release-unsigned.apk> alias_name
```

hope this help others who comes to this stack....

Answer (score 0):

In the application root:

```
cd platforms/android
./gradlew assembleRelease
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <myappname.keystore> app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk <myappname>
```

I've suppossed you are really using Cordova not Ionic.

Comment: I tried this, but it shows the same result as jarsigner: unable to open jar file: app-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: @JavithJ Check assembleRelease finished with success

Comment: it shows this error message " jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: "

Comment: @JavithJ You should modify the text into <> with your desired names.